# SWT - how to listen for mouse events, and retrieve their absolute position?

Tags: java, swt

I am capturing mouse events inside of a shell with Composites by adding a Filter.

For now the events are positioned relative to the Composites, where they occure.
How can I retrieve MouseEvents absolute position? 
(Absolute position is the position with 0,0 in the left uper corner of the display).

```
parentShell.getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            //do not know the absolute position here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Control#toDisplay(int, int)` to convert any relative coordinates to display relative absolute values.

```java
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.widget instanceof Control) {
        Point absolutePos = ((Control) event.widget).toDisplay(event.x, event.y);
        ...
    }
}
```

The above will work if the event you received is a mouse event, which it is in your example. You can also use `Display#getCursorLocation()` at any point to get absolute mouse location if you do not have a mouse event at hand.

Answer (score 5):

Following saved my day:

```
System.out.println("Click: " + parentShell.getDisplay().getCursorLocation());
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of would be to use the getLocation() method to get the relative position of the widget with the listener to its parent.  Use the method recursively until you get to the top composite and/or the Display.  Add in the relative coordinates of the event to get the absolute coordinates. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    parentShell.getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
           Point p = Display.getCurrent().map(null, null, event.x, event.y);
        }
    });
```